# How to print paragraphs in twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I have a content type, basic, where i have added a Paragraph field `field_pr` that has two fields: `field_text`, `field_color`. I have a twig template `node--basic--full.html.twig` where I want to print the value of the paragraph field `node.field_pr`.

`node.field_pr` can have between one and ten paragraph values.

When I print the array for `content.field_pr`, I get a huge array. However, I only want the values from the `field_pr.field_text` and field_pr.field_color. How would I be able to do this from the node twig template?

I have tried the following but cannot seem to access the values. What am I missing?

```
{% for field in content.field_pr %}
   {{ field[loop.index0].entity.field_text.value }}
   {{ field[loop.index0].entity.field_color.value }}
{% endfor %}

{% for field in content.field_pr %}
   {{ field[loop.index0]['#paragraph'].field_text.value }}
   {{ field[loop.index0]['#paragraph'].field_color.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is an image of the array that is printed for the `node.field_pr` field. 
[image: array that is printed for the node.field_pr field]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible with your current approach. Here is how I would approach this.

In your node template file just do a `{{ content.field_pr }}`

Create a template file for your paragraph.

> paragraph__[view_mode] (e.g. paragraph--default.html.twig)
>
> paragraph__[type] (e.g. paragraph--image.html.twig)
>
> paragraph__[type]__[view_mode] (e.g.
>   paragraph--image--default.html.twig)
>
> <sub>source: [Theming in Paragraphs for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/paragraphs/theming-in-paragraphs-for-drupal-8)</sub>

In **paragraph--[type].html.twig** you do `{{ content.field_text }}` and `{{ content.field_color }}`

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but how do I render paragraph.html.twig on my template file (page.html.twig)?

Comment: @clestcruz why not in node.html.twig?

Comment: @NoSssweat node.html.twig? Sorry I was trying to figure out how I can just print the values from my paragraph to my templates file. So far I've managed to create a paragraph.html.twig. I'm still new to Drupal apologies

Comment: @clestcruz, yes you'll need to create node--[content-type-name].html.twig. Ex: node--articles.html.twig and follow my answer.

Comment: @NoSssweat Not sure if this is the same or different but what I did was created a page--articles.html.twig

Comment: @clestcruz node is inside page. More specifically the `{{ page.content }}` part outputs the node twig. You're better off using node because page contains the entire page structure. Page It's not meant to be used for printing fields.

Comment: @NoSssweat Hmm well this is new to me. Most of my content type in drupal are using page--name-of-content-type.html.twig and not node.html.twig to render the values from the fields. So you're telling the correct  way to print the fields is to use node.html.twig instead?

Comment: @clestcruz yes exactly, the drupal way is to use node.htm.twig to print node fields. If you have a block, you use block.html.twig.

Comment: @NoSssweat ok, but how do I fetch or print the values from the paragraphs to my node.html.twig I tried calling it like a partial template `{% include '@iom/layout/paragraphs/paragraph--multimedia.html.twig' %}`

Comment: @clestcruz read my answer. First you print the paragraph field in node.html.twig then create a paragraph template file (if you want).

Comment: @clestcruz if you haven't yet, you need to go to your content type's manage fields and a paragraph field. Then you just simply print this field in node.html.twig just like any other field, nothing special. BTW no need to `{% include %}` any template.

Comment: @clestcruz i recommend using what NoSssweat said. Use `node.html.twig` and display the field using `{{content.field_machine_name_paragraph}}`. Then enable [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) and you can create a new twig template from there.

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks for referring me here... I'm trying to do something similar to above, But my paragraph template isn't overriding. My field in a content type is called "field_legal_section", referencing a paragraph type called "legal_section"... so I created "paragraph--field-legal-section.html.twig" and dropped {{ content.id }} & {{ content.field_section_title }}. But content type template is just rendering default values for the token in my content type template ( {{ content.field_legal_section }} ) . What might I be missing?

Comment: @turpentyne Did you place it in `/themes/your_theme/templates` folder? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: @NoSssweat I've done both - placed in the template folder of my theme and cleared the cache.

Comment: @NoSssweat update... I figured out the main problem.. Your example above looks like it's naming the template for the paragraph field within the content type. That's what I assumed was needed. When I change the template to my paragraph type's name (which is slightly different) it works - although it's not showing the field ID, which is my primary goal.

Comment: @turpentyne Good catch! What exactly are you referring to when you say field ID? the machine name of the field?  `field_legal_section`  or ???

Comment: @NoSssweat Not the machine name, but a unique id... Maybe it's called something else? Basically, each paragraph entry ends up with a sequential number? I can see it when I pull the paragraph in a view using "Paragraph: ID" , so I presumed I could get it with just {{ content.id }} ... but no luck.

Comment: @NoSssweat I just tried {{ paragraph.id() }} and {{ content.id() }}.. it still didn't work. Maybe at this point I need to make a new question for this. I haven't found an answer that quite works yet

Comment: @turpentyne you can get it with `{{ elements['#paragraph'].id() }}`

Answer (score 8):

To print paragraph fields in a loop (for sliders, etc.) in `page--content-type.html.twig` use below snippet:

```
{% for item in node.field_paragraph_mac_name %}
  {{ item.entity.field_title.value }}
  <img src="{{ file_url(item.entity.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: To print **alt** tag, use `alt="{{item.entity.field_image.alt}}"`.

Comment: Why we can't use {{ item.entity.field_title }} directly? The problem is for field such as "body" that need specific rendering. Using  {{ item.entity.field_body.value }} will requiere to use an usafe {{ item.entity.field_body.value|raw }}.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this one out. With [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) enabled you can print paragraphs from the node object without using content:

```
{% for item in node.field_my_paragraph_field %}
     {{ drupal_entity('paragraph', item.target_id) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just use `{{ content.field_my_paragraph }}` instead, does exactly the same, is cache safe, is more performant, and does not require an extra module.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer by user33560. If you have have nested paragraphs and you want to print or get the 2nd-level paragraph fields from within the 1st-level `paragraph.html.twig`:

```
{% set paragraph_name = content.field_paragraph_name %}

{% for item in paragraph_name['#items'] %}
    {{ drupal_entity('paragraph', item.target_id) }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can also use `{{ content.field_paragraph_name }}` to print all paragraph items, or print a subset such as `{{ content.field_paragraph_name.field_example }}`. Use `{{ content.field_paragraph_name|without('field_example') }}` to temporarily suppress the printing of a given child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{ node.ref_field_name.entity.field_name.value }}`