# How to print particular referenced paragraphs in twig?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have a content type (say "Ranking") with following fields:

[image: content]

field_paragraph can reference any number of different paragraphs created with the Paragraphs Module:
[image: paragraphs]

So when I print

```
{{ content.field_paragraph }}
```

in a template for this node (say node--ranking--full.html.twig), Drupal renders it starting from field.html.twig and iterating

> for item in items

over every referenced paragraph and their twigs.

But I need to print a single referenced paragraph (like sub_ranking) somewhere else in my node--ranking--full.html.twig.

Searching through answers to similiar questions and trying to understand anything from kint() I have already produced some crazy variations, none of which worked:

```
{{ content.field_paragraph.entity.field_sub_ranking.value }}
{{ content.field_paragraph.0.entity.field_sub_ranking.0.value }}
{{ content.field_paragraph.0.entity.sub_ranking.0.value }}
{{ content.field_paragraph[0]['#node'].field_sub_ranking.0.value }}
{{ content.field_paragraph[0]['#node'].field_sub_ranking.value }}
{{ content.field_paragraph.0.entity.field_paragraph.0.entity.sub_ranking.0.value }}
{{ content.field_paragraph.0.entity.field_paragraph.0.entity.field_sub_ranking.0.value }}
```

How can I render my referenced sub_ranking in my node template?

Comment: This is a weird implementation! Why not split out the `sub_ranking` paragraph to a separate field if it needs to be separate? Anyway, I'd achieve this by using PHP, using a preprocessor like `hook_preprocess_node`, grab the values of `field_paragraph` and loop through it to find your sub_ranking paragraph. Then just render it into a different variable: `$variables['sub_ranking_paragraph'] = $paragraph->view();` and you can print it in twig: `{{ sub_ranking_paragraph }}`

Comment: Definitly agree with Beebee here, restructure your content instead of doing code here. If that is not possible, you could also use the Twig tweak module, which provides a `{{ drupal_entity('paragraph', NUMERIC_ID) }}` render operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print paragraphs in twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247023/how-to-print-paragraphs-in-twig-template)

Comment: Thank you, @Beebee. I have split it to a separate field and rendered it that way.