# Specifying display of a new Paragraph type with images using HTML/twig?

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I created "figure" Paragraphs type, which **contains an image field** and a caption field. How **(from start to finish)** do I specify in HTML/twig how to render this new Paragraphs type?

As an example, how would I specify that the output would generate following code?

```
<figure>
  <img src="image">
  <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - did you make a twig file for this paragraph type with the markup you want to have? What part of that is not working?

Comment: @Kevin no, the process you described is what I'm looking for. I believe I've found [an article describing the process](https://medium.com/stationfive/how-to-create-a-paragraph-template-within-drupal-8-2203f6ed6c3b). and will submit the answer once I figure it out, assuming someone doesn't answer the question by then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print paragraphs in twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247023/how-to-print-paragraphs-in-twig-template)

Comment: @leymannx no, that question is about looping through an array. This is a basic question about how to create a custom twig template from start to finish.

Comment: You should definitely read the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/working-with-twig-templates) first then. It makes not much sense repeating them here. This then also makes your question too broad, don't you think so?

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't realized when first posting that this is the same as general theming and was expecting instructions like this within the Paragraph documentation. I believe I'm 90% there, but for some reason the code isn't working. 

Setting up debugging is apparently a whole major project in itself on this platform. Installed dev/kint, but then when trying to use it ran into the "mysql has gone away". problem. This is an utter nightmare trying to accomplish something that should be very straightforward. And RTFM isn't a reason to close/vote down a question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @leymannx does the answer below seem too broad?

Comment: This is completely up to you I think. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal, the specifying the generation of HTML from Paragraph types (as well as other types in Drupal) is done via the misnomer "theming."

- First [create a
  sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/creating-sub-themes).
- Next, copy the
  `/modules/contrib/paragraphs/templates/paragraph.html.twig` file into
  your sub-theme's templates folder and name it
  `paragraph--figure--default.html.twig`.
- Add the following code below the `set classes` closing brace `%}` which specifies the parameters for the image you'd like to display.

  ```
  {%
    set imagestyle = {
      '#theme':      'image_style',
      '#style_name': 'large',
      '#uri':        content.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value,
      '#alt':        content.field_image['#items'].entity.alt,
      '#attributes': { class: 'myimage' },
    } 
  %}
  ```
- Last, replace `{{content}}` with the code below:

  ```
  <figure>
      {{ imagestyle }}
      <figcaption>{{ content.field_caption }}</figcaption>
  </figure>
  ```

Note: Using `{{ content.field_image }}` directly inside `<figure>` instead of specifying a structure with theme `image_style` **will not work**.

Comment: You would usually define your image style settings and other display settings on the paragraph's Manage Display screen. If you did that then you could just output `{{ content.field_image }}` in your twig template. I wouldn't recommend doing this in the way you have here unless you're just totally forgoing the manage display screens on your entities. No Drupal developer would ever expect this to be implemented like this.